# If X~$\mathscr N(-5,1)$ what would be $\Bbb P(X \ge -4)$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Can anyone explain the following solution,

$=\Bbb P\left(\displaystyle\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \ge \frac{-4-(-5)}{1}\right)$

$=\Bbb P(Z \ge 1)$

$=0.5 - \Bbb P(0<Z<1)$

$=0.5 - 0.3413$

$=0.1587$ Ans.

Comment: If $X$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ then $(X-\mu)/\sigma$ is standard normal (mean 0, variance 1). You can use tables or software to get probabilities for the standard normal distribution.

Comment: @mark999, when should I understand that my problem requires a Table to solve the problem?

Comment: If you need probabilities relating to a normal distribution then it's very likely that a table or software is required.

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind that solution is that your original distribution is [invariant to translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translational_symmetry);  simplistically that one can add (or subtract) a quantity $a$ to the probability distribution of $X$ and the shape of that probability distribution of $X$ will remain the same.

The solution you present effectively says  that the question $P(X \ge -4)$   for $X \sim N(-5,1)$ can be answered for $X_{new} \sim N(0,1)$ if you also shift your original question such that is asks: $P(X_{new} \ge 1)$; here $\alpha$ is simply $5$ so you have $X_{new} = X + 5$. The answer emphasises the fact that the new distribution is $N(0,1)$ by using the symbol $Z$ to show that the new variable is [standardised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_scorehttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score).

In any case you need to use the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of the normal distribution to get your answer (function `pnorm` in R).
In R you could do something like:

```
1- pnorm( -4, mean = -5, sd = 1)
# 0.1586553
```

to get the exact answer directly without resorting to translating the probability distribution $X \sim N(-5,1)$. The answer you describe prompts you to use:

```
1- pnorm( 1, mean = 0, sd = 1)
# 0.1586553
```

so you query the distribution $X_{new} \sim  N(0,1)$. Both methods will return the same results:

```
all.equal( 1- pnorm( 1, mean = 0, sd = 1), 1- pnorm( -4, mean = -5, sd = 1))
# TRUE
```

My suggestion would be to forget about tables, tabulations and related stuff and focus to the idea that each probability is an area under a curve. If you appreciate that, then you just look around for a function that gives the *size of the slice* you are examining.