# If $X \sim \mathcal N(2,4)$, find the value of $P(X\ge3.5)$

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

> If $X \sim \mathcal N(2,4)$, find the value of $P(X\ge3.5)$.

**My attempt:**

Given that, $\mu = 2$ and $\sigma^2 = 4$.

$\Bbb P(X \ge 3.5) = \int_{3.5}^x{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \cdot\pi \cdot4}}\cdot e^{\frac{-(t-2)^2}{2 \cdot 4}}}dt$

Comment: Why are you asking effectively the same question you asked yesterday? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245582/if-x-mathscr-n-5-1-what-would-be-bbb-px-ge-4

Comment: @mark999, coz, I wanted a different point of view, a different way of solving this problem.

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but, for some reason, I thought N(mu,sigma) means the second number is the standard deviation, not the variance.

Comment: @mark999, besides, there were no satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate this by first changing the expression-

$P(X \ge 3.5) = 1 - P(X \lt 3.5)$

Then when you do the integration of the changed term, you have a limit of $-\infty$ to `3.5`, which you can calculate easily.

Comment: Not -infinity to 3.5 ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at one of the definitions of the **PDF**,

$1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$

If f(x) has a support then,

$1 = \int_{S}f(x)dx$

Or like what @nafizh pointed out you could flip the integration or in it's current form use the limit from 3.5 to $\infty$. That's what I was hinting at.

The $x$ value would give you something similar to the **CDF**. The definition of the **CDF** is:

$ F_x(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(x)dx$

Comment: Is the rest of them ok? like, the formula in use?

Comment: @anonymous in short yes. The wikipedia pages are probably a good resource to confirm on your own. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: some people  use z-scores. If this process in correct, why were they using z-scores? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245582/if-x-mathscr-n-5-1-what-would-be-bbb-px-ge-4